# Building a graphic neural network (GNNs) model from my own dataset (tabular dataset)

Tags: predict, gnn

I am intended to build a GNN. I am using my own dataset (tabular dataset), so to build a graph I can't use benchmark datasets as I have my own dataset. How can I build a graph first and then build a model to predict whether a participant needs treatment or not according to some features in the dataset? The problem is a classification problem.

So, could you please help me with the main steps to do that?

Thanks